# override the save method in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want the create field to change when the price field changes, that is, if I change the rest of the fields, the create field will not change and will remain the same.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    information = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Take a look at https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#field-tracker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a signal like this:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils import timezone

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Product)
def update_create_field(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    try:
       _pre_save_instance = Product.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
       if _pre_save_instance.price != instance.price:
          instance.create = timezone.now() #here you can specify any value you want
    except Exception as e:
       print('Error updating create field!')
       print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save your initial values in `__init__`, and check them before save:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    # Remove auto_now=True, it does not allow to set values by yourself.
    create = models.DateTimeField()
    discount = models.IntegerField()
    information = models.TextField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.create = self.create or datetime.now(UTC)

        self._initial_price = self.price

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.price != self._initial_price:
            self.create = datetime.now(UTC)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I also recommend to avoid using auto_now=True, since it disables ability to set values in field (they're gonna be ignored and overridden during db save) which makes testing and working with such fields harder. Instead just do it in `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite `__init__` and `save` on the model as an easy alternative

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._price_dirty = self.price
```

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self._price_dirty != self.price:
            self.create = timezone.now()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```